# Change starting direction of caret on Bootstrap 4 dropdown

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I can't believe this is as difficult as it seems.  I want to use a Bootstrap dropdown list, but I want the caret to start off facing right and then point downward when the dropdown has been expanded.  Rotating the caret as it is 90 degrees, is not the issue.  The issue is how do I begin with the caret pointing to the right.  Do I have hide the caret and totally replace it with something different?

CSS for rotation:

```
    .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    /*for animation*/
    .dropdown-toggle:after {
        transition: 0.7s;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <span class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span>
           &nbsp; Dropdown Example

        </span>
    </span>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

> Update

For @mahan who believes 'I must be doing something wrong".  Here is the code for my test page in which the caret does appear pointing to the right, but it does not rotate and the menu does not expand:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>TestPage</title>
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

<style>
         .dropdown-toggle::after {
             border-top: .3em solid transparent !important;
             border-right: .3em solid transparent !important;
             border-bottom: .3em solid transparent !important;
             border-left: .3em solid !important;
             vertical-align: middle !important;
             transition: 0.7s;
         }

         .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded="true"]:after {
             transform: rotate(90deg);
             /*
     You may transform origin of the caret.
    */
             transform-origin: 0.15em 0.32em;
         }
</style>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Dropdown button
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.4.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of replacing your caret this solution should work after doing display none to your caret icon. I am giving this alternative answer because i can not see working code in question

```
   .dropdown-toggle::after {
    content: ">";
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. Now it works https://liveweave.com/IMiEIs

Comment: I realized now it works also without content: ">"; so you need just transform : rotate(270deg)

Answer (score 0):

this one makes dropdown face down

```js
<div class="dropdown">
</div>
```

this one makes it open to the right then down.

```js
<div class="dropright">
</div>
```

Thats what bootstrap website shows.

Comment: I don't want the list to open to the right.  I want the caret to point to the right.